# Does PyCharm have autocomplete file path?

Tags: python, pycharm

In the IDLE that comes with Python if I were to type :

```
a='c:\
```

A list with the file contents of the directory is displayed for suggestion.  With Pycharm if I enter :

```
a='c:\
```

No list of the contents inside the directory is displayed. If I press 'control + space', PyCharm's auto-complete suggestions are a list of functions and variables inside my code. Does PyCharm have the capabilities to auto-complete file path suggestions within code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes it does, but you need to inject language in order to do so. Let me demonstrate:

http://youtu.be/4dh_yzgfXxE

I had to use video, since I think that’s the clearest way to explain how this works.

Comment: Do you need Professional edition for this? Because 'alt+Enter' does nothing for me and I can't seem to find any reference of language injection anywhere in the settings panel.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes :(

Comment: I have the Community Version, I press Ctrl+Enter, then add Inject Language and Reference, then File Reference. But when I press Ctrl+Space, I get "No suggestions"! This very frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

For anybody stumbling upon this (like me), here is a plugin which doesn't need `Inject Language and Reference` from the Professional Edition:

[File Path Autocomplete Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11088-file-path-autocomplete)

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me on PyCharm Community Edition 2022.2:

```py
# language=file-reference
a='./Foo.pdf'
```

([source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-language-injections.html#use-language-injection-comments))