# Make PyCharm recognize string as path

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, code-completion

I am working with Python 3.4.

When I use IDLE and start typing, e.g.,

`my_main_folder = "C:/Us"`

in the editor window, and then press `Ctrl + Space`, IDLE offers me all subfolders of `C:`, and if I press `Tab`, the string is completed to `"C:/Users"`.

That means that IDLE (or Python Shell) is able to recognize a string as a path.

How to make PyCharm (Community edition) do that?

Comment: Thank you for response. However, by following the link in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43419345/2281318) answer, I found out that my question is probably a duplicate ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Its not able in Community Edition Pycharm. But it can be done in Professional Edition Pycharm. I would suggest you to move to Professional Edition.
>
> [Does PyCharm have autocomplete file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353588/does-pycharm-have-autocomplete-file-path)

BUT,There is a work around for it in Community Edition.

`Place caret in such place and press Alt+Enter -- see if you will have "Inject language or reference" option in appeared menu. If it's present -- use it and choose "File Reference" there.`

- NOTE 1: this option may not be available if string is empty or has less than 2 characters in it
- NOTE 2: this is temp injection -- AFAIK it will be lost after IDE restart (and you will need to do it again if needed)

`Otherwise: select desired file in Project View panel and use "Copy Reference" -- it will copy a file path relative to the project root -- you may only need to add leading "/"...`

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206574619-Autocompleting-relative-paths

Answer (score 5):

After searching I found this answer:

> `can we tab through paths, in the same way you can in the terminal?`
>
> No, it's not posible:(
>
> `I wrote a plugin for Komodo called AutoCode that allowed me to ALT+Click on files in the Project view, and it would automatically resolve the right path`
>
> You can use 'Copy reference'  in file right-click menu to copy file path relative to project root to clipboard. But this action doesn't unfortunately take resource roots into account

However, you can use `CNTRL-SPACE` twice and it will present a list of paths and files, example:

[image]

For a detailed description of this information see [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207019345-How-do-I-get-path-auto-completion-to-enter-paths-relative-to-my-public-folder-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```py
# language=file-reference
a='./Foo.pdf'
```

This worked for me on PyCharm Community Edition 2022.2.
([source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-language-injections.html#use-language-injection-comments))